# Azure Instance metadata service

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

My understanding of the internal working of Azure system managed identities using Azure Instance Metadata Service is that every VM has its own unique service principal created with Azure AD and a unique pair of public - private key pair associated with it.

The private key is maintained on the VM and is used to sign the access token that can be fetched using /identity API endpoint on the Azure instance metadata service.

Is the unique identity of this VM instance tied to this private key only or is there more to it? If a bad actor is able copy the private key across to a different VM, can the bad actor impersonate a given VM? Or is there more that goes into generation of this access token than just the private key?

Comment: Have you seen this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-managed-identities-work-vm#how-it-works ?

Comment: Thanks for that link! That helps me get more clarity. I am looking at system assigned managed identities. I see that a client id and certificate associated with the VM is presented to authenticate into Azure AD to get back an access token. 

So, the identity of this VM hinges on the client id and certificate. So, does this mean if the the client id and certificate are copied away onto another VM, then the target VM can be impersonated?

Comment: The client_id  / certificate are not on the VM, they are on the IMDS. Because the managed identity is assigned to your VM, only your VM can request a token to the IMDS.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answers my question

Comment: Also my answer applies for system assigned identity. for user assigned identity, it s different as you can assignt he same identity to multiple azure resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just make a summary here: @Thomas Provided a detailed and professional explanation. Based on [How MSI works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-managed-identities-work-vm#how-it-works) and [how to get access token via managed identity on Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token),as you can see, the whole process to get access tokens is a `GET` function, no private keys or secrets are provided so there is no worry about that someone steals them and use them on other VMs. As @Thomas said :

> Only your VM can request a token to the IMDS

If you issue has been solved, please mark this post to close this case,thanks!